# Replace Words in a line from a file in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace certain words in file which has mutliplelines. Below is the code I wrote. Please note I am still learning python.

```
ParsedUnFormattedFile = io.open("test.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8", closefd=True).read()

remArticles = {' a ':'', ' the ':'', ' and ':'', ' an ':''}

for line in ParsedUnFormattedFile:
    for i in remArticles.keys():
           words = line.split()
           ParsedReplacementFile = ParsedUnFormattedFile.replace(words,remArticles[i])

    FormattedFileForIndexing =  io.open("FormattedFileForIndexing.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8", closefd=True)
    FormattedFileForIndexing.write(ParsedReplacementFile)
```

If I am replacing by directly reading a line, it replaces only 1 word out of all words. It's usually 'the' in my system.

So I wanted to split and look for ever word and then replace it. However I get below error:

```
line 14, in <module>
    ParsedReplacementFile = ParsedUnFormattedFile.replace(words,remArticles[i])
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

How can I get this rectified?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems.

1. `ParsedUnFormattedFile` is a **string**, not a file, because you've called `.read()`. That means your `for line in ParsedUnFormattedFile` loop does not iterate through the lines in the file, but the individual characters.
2. Each time the `for i in remArticles.keys():` loop runs, a new value is assigned to `ParsedReplacementFile`. It will only retain the last one.
3. You're overwriting the file `FormattedFileForIndexing.txt` in each iteration of your `for line in ParsedUnFormattedFile:` loop.

It's probably best to redo everything from scratch.

```
remArticles = {' a ':'', ' the ':'', ' and ':'', ' an ':''}

with io.open("test.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as ParsedUnFormattedFile:
    with io.open("FormattedFileForIndexing.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as FormattedFileForIndexing:
        for line in ParsedUnFormattedFile:
            for i in remArticles:
                line= line.replace(i, remArticles[i])
            FormattedFileForIndexing.write(line)
```

Comment: for the love of god use some pep8 styling

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Never even read pep8. I hate treating code like text. Anyhow, I've pretty much copied OP's code, so don't hate me too much.

Comment: Give me properly formatted readable code anyday, some questions I literally cannot look at this being one of those. It actually helps to push the beginners in the right direction, it makes code more readable for people trying to answer it and  is likely to get more people willing to answer it so everyone wins.

Comment: @Rawing, how does don't be a tool and write python code as it should be written work for you?

Comment: @Rawing, relax it was a joke.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: It errors again
    FormattedFileForIndexing.write(line)
TypeError: must be unicode, not str

Comment: `
with io.open("out.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as ParsedUnFormattedFile:
            with io.open("FormattedFileForIndexing.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as FormattedFileForIndexing:
              for line in ParsedUnFormattedFile:
                for i in remArticles:
                  line = line.replace(i, remArticles[i])
            FormattedFileForIndexing.write(line)

`

Answer (score 1):

When you call `split()`, you return a list.

```
'a b c asd sas'.split()
['a', 'b', 'c', 'asd', 'sas']
```

Instead, replace before you split, or concat the list back into a string and then replace.  To concatenate as list to a string:

```
words = ''.join(words)
```

EG:

```
''.join(['a','b','c'])
>>> 'abc'
```

Comment: :replacing before splitting will not help me, because I have  to check for every word and then replace. If I don't split, the entire line is being looked only once and only 1 word out of all the remArticles is getting replaced.  For example I have test.txt which has below line

" the file that is being edited is a test file and for testing purpose only. this is to remove articles like a , the , and , an , etc,."

Comment: Now if I write code as:

for line in ParsedUnFormattedFile:
    for i in remArticles.keys():
          
           ParsedReplacementFile = ParsedUnFormattedFile.replace(line,remArticles[i]), then my output is:

file that is being edited is a test file and for testing purpose only. this is to remove articles like a ,, and , an , etc,.

my output is:

file that is being edited is a test file and for testing purpose only. this is to remove articles like a ,, and , an , etc,.

only "the" got replaced